# Issue while running "composer require lorisleiva/laravel-search-string"

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I've been trying to install lorisleiva/laravel-search-string but I keep on getting this error.
Need this library for the search functionality.
Even composer update gives the same error. (just the problem 2 in case of update).
I have added the composer.json down below as well. Hope this will okay.
Need some guidance.
[image]

```
`{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "asm-laravel-admin-ext/tmeditor": "^1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.7",
    "cartalyst/stripe": "~2.0",
    "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^7.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
    "encore/laravel-admin": "^1.7",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "james.xue/laravel-admin-sortable": "^1.0",
    "laravel-admin-ext/config": "^1.1",
    "laravel-admin-ext/helpers": "^1.2",
    "laravel-admin-ext/log-viewer": "^1.0",
    "laravel-admin-ext/redis-manager": "^1.3",
    "laravel-admin-ext/scheduling": "^1.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.2",
    "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.1",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.4",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "league/oauth2-client": "^2.4",
    "nazmulb/mac-address-php": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "1.7.1",
    "socialiteproviders/discord": "^2.0.2",
    "socialiteproviders/twitch": "^5.2",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.17",
    "tightenco/ziggy": "^0.9.3",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0"
},
"require-dev": {

    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.dev', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}`
```

Comment: Could you post your `composer.json`?

Comment: I've updated the question with composer.json.

Comment: Please share the error message in readable form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Also, I don't think that the given error message is related to the package you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given error message tells it all: currently, you have `league/oauth1-client` installed in v1.7.0 due to any other requirement, and that package is not compatible with `guzzlehttp/guzzle`v7. You should start checking **why** that first package got installed through `composer why league/oauth1-client` - this package has been updated the last time four years ago, and as you also require `league/oauth2-client`, you could be safe to remove it

Answer (score -1):

You are using laravel 7, I think this package is not support in laravel 7, it will support in laravel 6

Comment: Run "composer dump-autoload" and "php artisan optimize:clear "

Comment: Just did, Issue is still there

Comment: Just have a look at https://packagist.org/packages/lorisleiva/laravel-search-string - the given package is compatible with Laravel v5, v6, and v7.

Comment: If it is compatible with v7 try again